# Python - Converting a Number to a Letter without an if statement

Tags: python, string, variables, integer

I am making a program for my own purposes (a naming program) that completely generates a random name. The problem is I cannot assign a number to a letter, so as a being 1 and z being 26, or a being 0 and z being 25. It gives me a SyntaxError. I need to assign this because the random integer (1,26) triggers a letter (if the random integer is 1, select A) and prints the name.

EDIT:

I have implemented your advice, and it works, I am grateful for this, but I wish to have my program create readable names, or more procedural. Here is an example of a name after I tweaked my program: ddjau. Now that doesn't look like a name, so I want it my program to work as if it were creating REAL names, like Samuel or other common names. Thanks!

EDIT (2):

Thanks, Adam, but I need a sort of 'seed' for the user to enter for the start of the name is. (Seed = A, Name = Adam. Seed = G, Name = George.) Should I do this by searching the file line by line, at the very beginning? If so, how do I do this?

Comment: I'll throw in help with the syntax error and leave others to answer your question.  The statement `1 = 'a'` will give you a `SyntaxError` because you are trying to assign to the literal 1.  You can only assign to a variable.  Just FYI. :)

Comment: you really have 130 variables? ever heard about strings, lists and loops?

Comment: Are you just looking for a way to get a random letter?  Try `from random import choice` then `choice([chr(c) for c in range(ord("a"), ord("z") + 1)])` or if you like shorter code (but this is a hack): `choice("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")`

Comment: If that was production code, we would have something DWTF worthy at our hands :x Also note that instead of the whole `+ 'a'` stuff we could obviously just call randint with 'a'-'z' for the range..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short Answer**
Look into Python dictionaries to allow the `1 = 'a'` type assignments.  Below I have working example that would generate a random name based on gender and a 'litter'.

**Disclaimer**
I do not fully understand (via the code) what you're trying to accomplish with char/ord and a random letter.  Also note having absolutely no idea of your design goals or requirements, I have made the example more complex than it may need to be for instructional purposes.

**Additional Resources**
* [Python Docs for dictionary](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)
* [Using Python dictionary relationship to search both ways](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/python/code/217019)

**In response to the last edit**
If you are looking to build random 'real' names, I think your best bet will be to use a large list of names and just pick a random one.  If I were you I'd look into something linking to the census results: [males](http://www.census.gov/genealogy/names/dist.male.first) and [females](http://www.census.gov/genealogy/names/dist.female.first).  Note that male_names.txt and female_names.txt are a copy of the list found at the census website.  As a disclaimer, I'm sure there is a more efficient way to load / read the file.  Just use this example as a proof on concept.

**Update**
Here's a quick and dirty way to seed the random values.  Again I am not sure that this is the most pythonic way or most efficient way, but it works.

**Example**

```
    import random
import time

def get_random_name(gender, seed):
    if(gender == 'male'):
        file = 'male_names.txt'
    elif(gender == 'female'):
        file = 'female_names.txt'

    fid = open(file,'r')
    names = []
    total_names = 0

    for line in fid:
        if(line.lower().startswith(seed)):
            names.append(line)
            total_names = total_names + 1

    random_index = random.randint(0,total_names)
    return names[random_index]

if (__name__ == "__main__"):
    print 'Welcome to Name Database 2.2\n'
    print '1. Boy'
    print '2. Girl'
    bog = raw_input('\nGender: ')
    print 'What should the name start with?'
    print 'A, Ab, Abc, B, Ba, Br, etc...'
    print ''
    l = raw_input('Leter(s): ').lower()

    new_name = ''
    if bog == '1': # Boy
        print get_random_name('male',l)
    elif bog == '2':
        print get_random_name('female',l)
```

**Output**

```
Welcome to Name Database 2.2

1. Boy
2. Girl

Gender: 2
What should the name start with?
A, Ab, Abc, B, Ba, Br, etc...

Leter(s): br
BRITTA
```

Comment: This works great, but I need a sort of 'seed' for the starting letter to be. 'Seed' as in F, would be Fred, or M would be Matthew. Maybe a chunk of code to search all lines for the first letter to be 'seed'. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`chr` (see [here](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#chr)) and `ord` (see [here](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#ord)) are the two functions you're looking for (though you already seem to know about the latter). Follow those links for a more detailed explanation.

The first gives you a one-character string based on the integer, the second does the reverse operaion (technically, it handles Unicode as well, which `chr` doesn't, though you have [`unichr`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#unichr) for that if you need it).

You can base your code on the following:

```
ch = "E"
print ord (ch) - ord ("A") + 1    # should give 5 for the fifth letter
val = 7
print chr (val + ord ("A") - 1)   # should give G, the seventh letter
```

Comment: I am using ord, but it finds the position of the letter in the alphabet, not assigns the letter to a position of the alphabet. I haven't tried chr yet, could you give me a brief explanation of it's use?

Comment: @Rob, I made the links a little more obvious so you can check those out for full details, but I also added  a little snippet at the end.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do, but you can convert a number into a letter with the [`chr()` function](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#chr). `chr()` takes an ASCII code, so if you want to use the range [0, 25] instead you can adapt it like so:

```
chr(25 + ord('a'))    # 'z'
```